# JS Удалить все пробелы в тексте кроме первого встречающегося

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Как удалить все пробелы в тексте кроме первого встречающегося?

Comment: Уточните: 1 первого пробела или первой последовательности пробелов?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вариант на чистой регулярке без использования функции

```js
var text = 'Как удалить все пробелы в тексте кроме первого встречающегося?';
text = text.replace(/(^[^ ]* )|[ ]+/g, '$1');
console.log(text);
```

Здесь первая группа захвата `(^[^ ]* )` (она захватит текст от начала строки до первого пробела + сам пробел) отработает только один раз и будет вставлена в результирующую строку без изменений `$1`, а затем все встреченные пробелы `[ ]+` будут удалены, так как первая группа захвата будет возвращать пустоту.

Comment: О, круто!!! Даже не подумал про такой вариант))

Answer (score 3):

Счетчик на пробелы повесить ;)

```js
var text = 'Как удалить все пробелы в тексте кроме первого встречающегося?';
var count = 0;
text = text.replace(/ /g, 
    function() {
        if (++count > 1) {
            return '';
        } else {
            return ' ';
        }
    });
console.log(text);
```

Comment: а зачем считать если нужно просто знать был ли уже пробел или нет

Comment: @Grundy, вы правы.

Answer (score 3):

**Современный подход**

Можно воспользоваться шаблоном неизвестной длины в блоке предварительного просмотра назад:

```js
const text = 'Как удалить все пробелы в тексте кроме первого встречающегося?';
console.log(text.replace(/(?<=\s.*?)\s+/gs, ''));
```

См. [пример работы выражения](https://regex101.com/r/x2VhKC/1). `(?<=\s.*?)` – блок предварительного просмотра назад, который находит позицию в строке, сразу перед которой есть пробельный символ, за которым следует 0 и более любых символов, как можно меньше, а `\s+` находит 1 и более пробельных символов.

**Старый ответ**

Так как сам движок регулярных выражений не имеет представления о том, какое совпадение по счёту он находит, необходимо самому добавить флаг и установить на `true`, если первое совпадение уже найдено.

Вот пример удаления последовательностей пробелов кроме первой:

```js
var s = "1  2 3 4 5   6    ";
var first = false;
var res = s.replace(/\s+/g, function($0) {
  if (!first) {
    first = true;
    return $0;
   } else return "";
})
console.log(res);
```

Если необходимо оставить только *первый* пробел из первой последовательности, замените выражение на

```
/\s/g
```

Обратите внимание на то, что `\s` находит любые пробельные символы, и если необходимо удалить только обычные пробелы (символ `\x20`), замените на `/ /` (см. ответ [@Visman](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186083/visman)). '`.

Есть способ обойтись без счётчика и без флажка. Используя `(^\S*\s*)?\s+`, можно проверить, была ли захвачен шаблон первой подмаски, и, если да, оставить, иначе - удалить:

```js
var s = "1  2 3 4 5   6    ";

// Если нужно оставить целую первую пробельную последовательность
var res = s.replace(/(^\S*)?\s+/g, function($0,$1) {
   return $1 ? $0 : "";
});
console.log(res);

// Если нужно оставить только 1-й пробел из первой пробельной последовательности
res = s.replace(/(^\S*)?(?!^)\s/g, function($0,$1) {
   return $1 ? $0 : "";
});
console.log(res);
```

**Подробности первой регулярки**

- `(^\S*)?` - захватывающая группа №1, 1 или 0 совпадений (необязательная), находит начало текста и 0 и более символов, отличных от пробелов
- `\s+` - 1 и более пробелов.

Во второй регулярке - `(^\S*)?(?!^)\s` - находится та же первая захватывающая группа, после которой стоит проверка на начало строки (`(?!^)`) (если мы в начале строки, следующий пробел пропускается), а `\s` найдет только один пробельный символ.

Comment: а нет какого-то look(ahead/behind), чтобы выбрались только пробелы перед которыми были пробелы? тогда функция не нужна будет

Comment: @Grundy: Точно одно: в JS RegExp это невозможно. В C# [`(?<!^\S*)\s+`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5e%5cS*%29%5cs%2b&i=1++2+3+4+5+++6++++&r=) оставит только первый пробел из первой последовательности пробелов, а [`(?<!^\S*\s*)\s+`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5e%5cS*%5cs*%29%5cs%2b&i=1++2+3+4+5+++6++++&r=) оставит первую последовательность. Короче, нужен lookbehind свободной длины.

Comment: @Grundy: я добавил ещё один способ, который тоже основан на использовании метода обратного вызова, но без использования счётчика / флажка.

Comment: 2 пробела осталось а не один

Comment: а вот интересно, надо было удалять второй пробел `1  2` или нет? здесь не совсем понятно, что хочет автор.

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan - этот момент в вопросе неясен. Я добавил оба варианта.

Comment: Вроде как ясно написано `Удалить все пробелы в тексте кроме первого встречающегося`

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan: Всё, исправил так, что даже первый пробел оставит.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  сейчас нормально)))

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, [look behind](//github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-lookbehind) - это уже stage 3 и под флагом реализовано в хроме, так что скоро станет можно. http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/esnext/

Answer (score 2):

Вариант без регулярок.

Можно воспользоваться [методом `split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), разбив строку по пробелам.

Далее вставить пробел после первого элемента и объединить массив с помощью [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```js
var text = 'Как удалить все пробелы в тексте кроме первого встречающегося?';

arr = text.split(' ');
arr.splice(1, 0, ' ');
console.log(arr.join(''));
```

Answer (score 2):

Захотелось немного поизвращаться:

```js
var text = "Как удалить все пробелы в тексте кроме первого встречающегося?"
console.log(text.split("").reverse().join("").replace(/ (?=.*? )/g,"").split("").reverse().join(""))
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант(ES6): с использованием методов [Split](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [Join](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), [Splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

```js
function delSpaces (s) {
    let arr = s.split(' ');
    let s1 = arr.splice(1).join('');
    return `${arr[0]} ${s1}`;
};
console.log(delSpaces('Убрать пробелы везде кроме первого'));
```

или вообще в одну строку, что возможно ухудшает читаемость:

```js
function delSpaces (s) {
    return `${s.split(' ')[0]} ${s.split(' ').splice(1).join('')}`;
};
console.log(delSpaces('Убрать пробелы везде кроме первого'));
```